# Best Practices. How to change a Nebular ngx-admin Component CSS

Tags: angularjs, angular, ngx-admin

Let's assume I need to change the behaviour or the CSS style of a Nebular/NGX-admin component. What should I do ?
What I reached so far is to change the module directly in node_modules/@nebular but I'm not sure this is a best practice.
Is there a workaround ?

Comment: You should never edit anything inside node_modules

Answer (score 1):

Yea it's an interesting question. I am using Nebular at one of my admin panels in production. And the most problems which you will get after modification of basic styles will touch you when you will try to update the version of Nebular/NGX-admin.

So my advice for you to keep all your customized styles in some separate file in root or `@theme`. Something like `nebular-custom.scss`. In this case, you will be able to separate your styles before the update.

But keep in mind that similar problems you can get if you will write your `Components` code in wrong places in the file structure. So, first of all, try not to change and not to write your `Components` in the `@core` module. Better do it in some separate module or at least folder. Also, nice practice will be to write all your `http` and `model` layers in the `@data` module.
After all, you should be able to update Nebular/NGX-admin with replacing `@core` and `@theme` modules with facing some minor issues.